# How can I pass this method as a function argument rather than inject the entire class

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, swift-protocols

I have created a project that contains my networking code. I have another project that contains some services and view controllers related to a users profiles.

My networking layer has the following interface

```swift
public protocol HTTPClientTask {
  func cancel()
}

public typealias HTTPClientResult = Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>

public protocol HTTPClient {
  /// The completion handler can be invoked in any thread.
  /// Clients are responsible for dispatching to the appropriate thread, if needed.
  @discardableResult
  func execute(_ request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (HTTPClientResult) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask
}
```

My concrete class conforms to `HTTPClient` and currently I am injecting this dependancy injection.

However this requires my profile module to be aware of my networking module. This creates a coupling between those modules I'd like to remove.

As `HTTPClient` only has a single method that returns a task, I thought I could perhaps update my profile module to accept the function signature instead of the client.

This way only the composition root within my app will be aware of both modules which I believe is acceptable.

What I cannot quite get my head around is how to represent the `HTTPClient` interface as a simple function.

I believe it is:

```swift
typealias ClientResult = Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>
typealias ClientMethod = (URLRequest, @escaping (ClientResult) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask
```

However I cannot represent the `HTTPClientTask` property also.

This should be an object with a method on that returns void.

Essentially I'd like to pass the `execute` method as an argument, but cannot workout how to represent it as a type without using the current protocols.

An example of how this interface is implemented can be found below:

```
public final class URLSessionHTTPClient: HTTPClient {

  private let session: URLSession
  private struct UnexpectedValuesRepresentationError: Error { }
  private struct URLSessionTaskWrapper: HTTPClientTask {
    let wrapped: URLSessionTask
    func cancel() {
      wrapped.cancel()
    }
  }

  public init(session: URLSession = .shared) {
    self.session = session
  }

  public func execute(_ request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (HTTPClientResult) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask {
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      completion(Result {
        if let error = error {
          throw error
        } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
          return (response, data)
        } else {
          throw UnexpectedValuesRepresentationError()
        }
      })
    }

    task.resume()
    return URLSessionTaskWrapper(wrapped: task)
  }
}
```

I have added a playground below, I hope makes it clearer.

```swift
import UIKit

public protocol HTTPClientTask {
  func cancel()
}

public typealias HTTPClientResult = Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>

public protocol HTTPClient {
  /// The completion handler can be invoked in any thread.
  /// Clients are responsible for dispatching to the appropriate thread, if needed.
  @discardableResult
  func execute(_ request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (HTTPClientResult) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask
}


public final class URLSessionHTTPClient: HTTPClient {

  private let session: URLSession
  private struct UnexpectedValuesRepresentationError: Error { }
  private struct URLSessionTaskWrapper: HTTPClientTask {
    let wrapped: URLSessionTask
    func cancel() {
      wrapped.cancel()
    }
  }

  public init(session: URLSession = .shared) {
    self.session = session
  }

  public func execute(_ request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (HTTPClientResult) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask {
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      completion(Result {
        if let error = error {
          throw error
        } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
          return (response, data)
        } else {
          throw UnexpectedValuesRepresentationError()
        }
      })
    }

    task.resume()
    return URLSessionTaskWrapper(wrapped: task)
  }
}

let client = URLSessionHTTPClient(session: .init(configuration: .ephemeral))

typealias ClientResult = Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>
typealias ClientMethod = (URLRequest, @escaping (ClientResult) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask // I want to remove the knowledge of `HTTPClientTask` from the typealias

class Loader {

  private let load: ClientMethod

  init(load: @escaping ClientMethod) {
    self.load = load
  }

  func get() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
    load(.init(url: url)) { result in
      print(result)
    }
  }
}


let loader = Loader(load: client.execute(_:completion:))

loader.get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `URLSessionTaskWrapper` is probably making it difficult to represent this without the use of an abstract interface such as `HTTPClientTask`.

You could perhaps return the `URLSessionTask` itself.

```swift
public protocol HTTPClient {
  @discardableResult
  func execute(_ request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (HTTPClientResult) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask
}

...
typealias ClientMethod = (URLRequest, @escaping (ClientResult) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask
```